# Is it legal to make Android app Paid of Monetize Ads if it contains YouTube videos

Tags: android, webview, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I am planning to develop an Android App for Kids Leaning.

In the initial screen, i will have list of topics like below. These topics will be loaded from a Database and each  link contains a href.

[image]

Now, once the kid click on any link, in the next activity, i am loading a WebView and the video is played in the WebView.

```
String frameVideo = "<html><body><iframe width=100%; height=100%; src="+strVideoURL+" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>";

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webView.loadData(frameVideo, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

Following is the screenshot how it looks like:
[image]

So is it legal to reference video as above?

In the above scenario, can i monetize the App. I dont want to show any Ads on the videoplayer activity, but wanted to place Ads on all other activities. Is it Legal? Please suggest.

Comment: Yes , you can place ads inside listing of videos of youtube. but you can't place ads in video playing screen of youtube (webview in your case). If you do so, your application will be rejected on play store while uploading.

Comment: Thanks Radhey for your reply. Can you please also let me know, is it fine to use WebView or do i need to use YouTubePlayer and YouTube API to play these videos?

Comment: you should go with `YouTube Android Player API` .(refer this https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/) ,and this one is sample https://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/how-to-play-youtube-video-in-android-app/ .